# What are the first historical examples of meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, history, example

I am researching the history of meta-analysis, and have found several interesting scholarly sources, going [O'Rourke](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2121629/) to [Hedges](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1149/abstract), just to name two recent ones.

On top of these authoritative sources, I am wondering if there are other interesting and to date overlooked early historical examples of meta-analysis, even if not that evident.

Do you know any one?

Comment: Easy to say, but this hinges on what you call meta-analysis precisely. If it is pooling and then analysing data from different projects as a collective, it's as old as you like. Presumably it doesn't depend on whether the authors used that term. Concretely, find a copy of  F. Yates and W. G. Cochran. 1938. The analysis of groups of experiments. _The Journal of Agricultural Science_ 28: 556-580. doi:10.1017/S0021859600050978. and see if it matches your criterion. Then look for older work or newer work that does. (The paper is reprinted variously, e.g. in collections of either author's papers.)

Comment: If you also want to trace the history of the forest plot perhaps Sindhu, F Journal of Advanced Nursing, 1996, 24:1152--1159 is the first example although not named as such.